# Setting up DNS for domain with both HTTP and Gemini and or Gopher protocols

Tags: networking, dns, http, protocol, cloudflare

I have my blog on domain `palashbauri.in`, which is a static hugo site hosted on Cloudflare Pages. DNS is managed by Cloudflare. Currently my domain `palashbauri.in` have CNAME record pointing to the blog.

So, my blog is available on port 80 and 443 with http(s).
If possible, how should I configure my DNS record to make the gemini and gopher protocol accessible on same domain such as

`gemini://palashbauri.in` , `gopher://palashbauri.in` ?

I know, I can make it work using subdomains such as `gemini://gemini.palashbauri.in` or `gopher://gopher.palashbauri.in`, but it would be nice to make it accessible without using subdomains?

> Short intro for Gemini protocol : TCP server protocol running on port 1965.

> Gopher protocol runs on port 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If possible, how should I configure my DNS record to make the gemini and gopher protocol accessible on same domain such as

That is only possible if *all* protocols are hosted on the same system. That is, you need to move your HTTP service out of Cloudflare and start hosting it on the same machine as Gemini/Gopher. (That is, you can use neither Cloudflare Pages *nor* Cloudflare proxy CDN.) When that's done, you don't need to do anything extra with DNS at all.

When you just make a regular query for A/AAAA records, DNS **doesn't know** what protocol you'll be using with that. All it knows is the domain name and record type being requested, so you *cannot* redirect some apps to the Cloudflare Pages server and other apps to your Gopher/Gemini server if they're all requesting the exact same name.

There are *some* protocols which have the client deliberately make a protocol-specific DNS query first – for example, email servers will look for MX records before A/AAAA, and Minecraft will look for SRV records at `_minecraft._tcp.<domain>` before it looks for A/AAAA on the domain itself, and that allows the mail server or the game server to be hosted on a completely different machine than everything else on the domain.

But for the majority of protocols that don't have such provisions, the only way to distinguish DNS requests made by Gemini clients from requests made by HTTP clients is to use different subdomains for them. (That's why subdomains like `ftp` and `www` were so commonly used in the first place.)

---

The only other workaround is to have a server that accepts all connections and *relays* some of them to another server. For example, your Gopher server could accept HTTP connections using a common "reverse proxy" and forward the requests to Cloudflare Pages – though you completely lose the advantages of hosting the site on CF that way. Alternatively, Cloudflare could proxy TCP connections on ports 70/1965 to your server, but I think that's part of their expensive enterprise plans only.

Comment: Then, I would stick to using subdomains. Thanks.